# Check on child page name from Parent Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a PageContext class which inherits from Page. I got several children classes that inherit from PageContext. In PageContext, I got a property "Permission". I need to set "Permission" property based on the Child page that is open.

This is my PageContext

```
 public class PageContext: Page
    {
        public string permission
        {
            get
            {
                 switch ( the open child page)
                 {
                     case 'A':
                           return 'Read';
                     default:
                          return 'Read';

                 }
            }

        }
    }
```

Can I achieve this in the parent class or do i have to do it in each child page ?

Comment: this is not a correct way to create permission. Permission depends on User or on some group of users. You should have different class which should handle this.

Comment: @mybirthname In my application a user can have different permissions for each page not only based on his role. So in the code above i'm trying to return the user permission for  the corresponding page

Comment: Then how you assign that permissions to user ?

Comment: You can make something like this: every child page to have Name property. Service.aspx-> services and the permission to be called ServicesView and so on. After that you have the permission name you can check if current user have it. I think you must put something in the child page everytime, there is no other way. I'm not sure that this is the best approach !

Comment: @aria User Permissions are saved in another property in the base class

Comment: @user3340627 How about change Permission prop to method ?

Comment: @aria Yes I'm thinking to get permissions using a method and setting a Permission Property with the result. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: So change it to method and pass page name to it then return permission? right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed something same your code to check user access in Page_Load of each page as following:

So I have a base MemberWebPage like:

```
 public abstract class MemberWebPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public virtual bool AutorizeUser()
    {
        return false;
    }
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

And all pages that inherited should implement base methods (AutorizeUser) like:

```
  public partial class UsersManagement :MemberWebPage
{
    public override bool AutorizeUser()
    {
        EnteredUser up = (EnteredUser)Session["UserProfile"];
        if (up == null)
            Response.Redirect("../LogIn.aspx");
        return up.HasAccess(PrimitiveActivity.UserManagement);
    } 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (!AutorizeUser())
            Response.Redirect("../Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

My HasAccess method will check user access from DB !

But I am still not very sure about your code, anyway you can follow these steps (this can be a solution):

1- Define 'PageName' as virtual string in your PageContext it will return null

2- Each derived class will override PageName

3- In PageContext 'Permission' property will return according to the PageName

So we have:

```
 public class PageContext : Page
{ 
    public virtual string PageName
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        } 
    }
    public string Permission
    {
        get
        {
            switch (PageName)
            {
                case "Page1":
                    return "Read";
                case "Page2":
                    return "Write";
                default:
                    return "None";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And derived classes just for example:

```
public class Page1 : PageContext
{
    public override string PageName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Page1";
        }
    }
}
public class Page2 : PageContext
{
    public override string PageName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Page2";
        }
    }
}
public class Page3 : PageContext
{ 
}
```

And at the end you can use something like this:

```
string p1Permission = (new Page1()).Permission;//Read
string p2Permission = (new Page2()).Permission;//Write
string p3Permission = (new Page3()).Permission;//None
```

Hope will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I also tried using "Request.PhysicalPath;" in page context and checking if my Page name is included in the page path, it worked fine too

Comment: For some reason when i tried setting the name using the override method, in the context class the names are null, could you possibly know what could be the problem ?

Comment: For the sake of time i set the permissions in each of the child pages directly but i might be able to get back to this at the end of my project. Thanks a lot for your concern.